# How to get the entire REALTIME document HTML/state as a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

For debugging purposes I need to get the realtime updated HTML.

I am using document.documentElement.innerHTML to get the current HTML inside the html tags of a document.
When I do this i noticed that not all changes that can be made by the user are included in the result of innerHTML.

What is included as I have tested so far:

- elements that where hidden (display:none) and which where set on non hidden after some user action
- checkbox states, checked or unchecked by the user

What is not included:

- auto suggestions elements which where added to an element after some user action
- form text fields values that where changed by the user
- changed states of combo boxes
- etc?

In short, I need a method that grabs all the HTML including every change made by the user or some script.
Would this require a complete traversal trough the DOM, reading all the elements and their attributes, or is there a more easy way?
(in the first case, I would be happy if someone can point me to such a script)

Comment: Anything that doesn't make a direct change to the DOM HTML will not be represented by innerHTML. One solution is to add events to those elements and save the state changes as attributes on them. This way when you get the HTML since attribute changes are directly seen in the HTML those values will be there. I do not believe there is an shortcut special function that will just give that to you.

Comment: Ok, we are talking about an extremely big web application, with many many forms, and really big forms, which also includes many differentiations on the basis of user types, projects etc. etc. Wouldn't there be some kind of method to read for instance a form text field value typed in by the users in one big go (traversal of the DOM)? Isn't this anywhere all accessible that way?

Comment: I mean you can literally select all the inputs or even every element and traverse over them and their children. I guess I would need to understand why you need a snapshot of all the HTML and the changes made to it to understand what the best solution there is or if there is an alternative.

Comment: The snapshot is intended for debugging of javascript errors, the application is filled with conditions based on types of user etc etc, so the HTML the users are getting served differs very much. It also contains inline scripting (which makes it hard to determine the real location of the script in the original source on the server). The value's filled in by the user or a script (a hidden field for instance) are also of importance cause many errors have to do with processing these values.
And as I said, the app contains so many forms and form fields, I was lookiing for a general/central approach

Comment: In addition: the javascript errors are sent to the server log whenever an error occurs, including some info about the error. I was thinking of adding that snapshot of the realtime state to the log, as a document. Cause at this moment, often i can't do much with just the information.

Comment: After some consideration. As I do not want to burden the client browser with more event handlers always keeping track of form elements, I am just gonna read the form element states when an error occurs, and include this in the error report. Seems like the most simple approach.

Comment: Sounds simple enough. Sorry had a busy work day so didn't have a chance to reply.